# Shiny cuts off dimple rCharts dates

Tags: shiny, rcharts

I just want a simple dimple chart in Shiny, where x-axis has dates, but somehow date labels get cut off out of visible svg area.

I tried resizing svg either in code or css, but it only results in the whole chart getting bigger and so the dates are cut off again. Margins, padding, nothing seems to work!

[Pic showing cut dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y4kp.png)

Comment: Can you provide reproducible example please

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045397/show-properly-x-labels-with-rcharts-and-dimplejs